# How to manually create a specific connected graph and run tests

Tags: python, networkx

I want to create a connected graph where each node represents an employee at my work. I want to be able to run a simulation of a cold spreading through the office. The people connected to the infected person have a certain probability to get the cold and it continues on. How can I do this?

Also will I be able to set a time limit on how long the infected person will stay infected?

Comment: Look up Agent Based Models to learn something about the domain. Search for mesa on github, it is a project to make the equivalent of netlogo in python.

Comment: might I suggest Epidemics on Networks (EoN) on github.  Still in very early stages, but aimed at things like this.  I'm developing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A (admittedly optimizable) version of what you're looking for, i believe could look something like this.

```
percentSpread = #integer representing percent chance of cold to spread
percentBetter = #chance someone who has the cold gets better
cold = #some node in your graph we'll call office, the first guy sick
sickness = [] #the array that keeps track of the people with colds in the office


def sickevent(percent): #lets us know if a sick person gets better or a nearby person gets sick
    if randint(1,100) < percent:
        return True
    else:
        return False

sickness.append(cold)
while len(sickness) >0:
    for sick in sickness:
        if sickevent(percentbetter):
             sick['issick'] = False
             sickness.remove(sick)
        else:
            for potential in office.neighbors(sick):
                if potential['beensick'] = False and potential['issick']=False:
                    if sickevent(percentspread):
                         potential['issick'] =True
                         potential['beensick'] = True
                         sickness.append(sick)
```

Should get you going. Plenty of customization possible. If you want to know who got sick before the sickness died, you can iterate through and check who has 'beensick' = true. note you should initialize all nodes to have the sickness related attributes = False.
You can change it to have certain spread or cure values based on the node or the edge. 
This graph assumes that someone can only get those sick they are connected to. If you want everyone to have a chance of getting everyone sick, you should have an initial graph that connects everyone (but not everyone to everyone) in some way and assigns a spread chance to each edge on a graph that connects everyone to everyone based on the distance from one another in the first graph or something of the like